# Can not prevent keyframes animating in page reload and resize

Tags: html, css, animation, sass, frontend

Keyframes animations happens on my breakpoints every time on resize my browser window. On 1125px and 768px. Also it happens when i reload page. I dont know what can i try here. Any help is highly appreciated ? my code is

````
    transform-origin: top right;
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    animation: 0.3s ease-in scalingXY-reverse;
}

.menu-open {
    transform-origin: top right;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    animation: 0.4s ease-in both scalingXY;
}

@keyframes scalingXY {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0, 0);
    }

    90% {
        transform: scale(1.02, 1.02);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}
@keyframes scalingXY-reverse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0, 0);
    }
}```
````

Comment: this animation should happen only when someone opens or closes menu

Answer (score 0):

### DOM Content Refresh

From what I understand, the DOM gets repainted on `@media` query breakpoints and on page refreshes. This means that the elements are being refreshed and the animations will play. I assume that when someone clicks on the menu button, it adds the `.menu-open` class to the menu, making it open (I would have to see your JavaScript if it doesn't)?

If the animations keep playing, this may mean that your menu may be open by default and not hidden. I would recommend that you make the menu invisible by using `visibility: hidden,` or remove it from the DOM using `display: none;` and then reverse those styles through the `.menu-open` class.

Answer (score 0):

I just got same exact problem myself. After checking several solutions only one worked for me. So you have to remove offending classes from elements right after animation happens. So here will be no animations to trigger on breakpoints while resizing.

```js
//get your element
var someElement= document.getElementById("someId");

//add animation end listener
someElement.addEventListener(supportedValue(), myEndFunction, false);


//define those functions in the beginning

function supportedValue() {

    var t;

    var evList = {
        'animation' : 'animationend',
        'webkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
        'MozAnimation' : 'mozAnimationEnd',
        'OAnimation' : 'oanimationend',
        'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd'
    };

    for (t in evList){
        if (someElement.style[t] !== undefined){
            return evList[t];
        }
    }
}

function myEndFunction(){
    someElement.classList.remove("offendingclass");
}
```